# Android Layout Background Using Previous Layout's View

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

This may sounds simple, but I really need help on it. I have searched for related topics but not found any.

Is it possible to set a layout which is displayed now to be the next layout's background? For example, now I display layout A, then I click a button which starts the layout B (on activity). I want layout A to be layout B's background. If yes, how to achieve it progmatically or by XML manipulation?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you take a look at this [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)?

Comment: [View.bringToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Apoorv Did you mean that it sould be like this on Layout B: 'android:background="@layout/layoutA" ' ?
I can't achieve it with that

Comment: you need to use fragments.http://ausmarton.blogspot.in/2014/01/preferencefragment-shows-up-with.html

Comment: I can't find any clue on link you gave me @Ramz , but I'll give it a try. An example would be a nice try for me, thanks

Comment: I seem can't find any clue myself on that @b1izzard, but I'll try to explore it. thanks